# Hortonworks Ranger credentials

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform

I have installed **HDP msi installer on windows server** with two nodes. After the installation i haven't accessed the **Ranger Portal** with or without valid credentials.
How can i change the Ranger credentials in HDP 2.0?

Comment: You can check the HDP documentation for this. Is this actually a technical question?

Comment: I have googled lot including HDP documentation, but can't find the solution. So that i posted here, it may be useful for someone who are all in my situation. Anyhow thanks for your contribute @Kumar

Answer (score 1):

By Ranger credentials if you mean Ranger Admin login, you can change it by :

1. Login to Ranger Admin at localhost:6080 with admin credentials
2. Click on Admin -> Profile from top right
3. Go to "Change Password" tab and change the password

Do let me know if you face any issues or you meant some other credentials.

Answer (score 1):

The default credentials are:

- username: admin
- password: admin

If you never configured anything, chances are that these still work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found your answer by now, but there's a way to set custom credentials for Ranger Admin UI without using the web UI.

In the install.properties file under ranger-admin directory, add the following property

```
rangerAdmin_password=<your_custom_password>
```

Now run `./setup.sh` inside your ranger-admin directory. Then you can login to Ranger Admin (i.e. http://localhost:6080) using

Username: **admin**

Password: **your_custom_password**